# Why does django create btree indexes on foreign key columns?

Tags: django, django-models

Django's `makemigrations` automatically creates a Btree index for each foreign key defined in the model.

This seems strange to me as foreign keys are normally used for equality-based joins and rarely, if ever for sorting.

Wouldn't it be better to use Hash index by default in such cases?

Comment: are you using postgresql????

Comment: yes, I noticed this on postgresql

Comment: yes then it will always create BTREE index as its default to postgres and not django